# How do I check if an item no longer exists in GameMaker Studio?

Tags: game-maker

Let's say I have an array of `objects[i,j]`, which has been fully populated by objects `obj_example`. I want to delete the `obj_example` at position [1,2]. That's simple, as `objects[1,2]` is currently pointing to that object (or is the object, or whatever logic Gamemaker uses).

But now, the object at `objects[1,2]` is destroyed.

What `if` statement would I use to check that makes `objects[1,2]` return an `undefined`(or null) value (but, clearly, not make the other, populated objects return such)?

Or how would I otherwise know that the `objects[1,2]` were destroyed?

EDIT: I added the following to my little project, after `object_handler` (which was made equal to the `objects[i,j]` to be deleted) was deleted. It returned "this is defined."

```
if (is_undefined(object_handler)) 
{
    show_message("this is undefined");
}
else{
    show_message("this is defined");
}
```

So...is_undefined(n) does not work for this purpose.

Comment: What does a destroyed object return currently? Just the object even though it is destroyed?

Comment: I am not sure, which is why I'm asking. I'm just running on the assumption that `is_undefined(objects[1,2])` works, but I'm hoping to get an answer from someone who actually knows.

Comment: Why don't you test if it works? That seems like a really easy way to find a solution before asking a question. Just print the value of the object before it dies and print the value of the object after. See how the value differs. If the printed value of the dead object is `null` or `undefined` or similar you know what to look for.

Comment: OK. I tested it, is_undefined(n) does not work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems you have to use `instance_exists(object)` to check if the object has been deleted or not. This will return `false` when the object has been deleted. So in your case do

```
if (!instance_exists(objects[1,2])) {
    //Does not exist
}
```

To be safe you could also set your variable to a predetermined value when it is destroyed, perhaps set `objects[1, 2]` to `undefined` so you know it doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: AWESOME! Plugged in `instance_exists` for `is_undefined` for my debugging code, and it works as expected.

Comment: Huh...well, game maker must have just patched or something, because, while it worked before, it's now saying that the instance exists, even though I didn't change anything related to the debugging code. It worked just fine 2 days ago!

Comment: @SangoProductions that's probably not the case. You're probably just making a small mistake that's difficult to see at first glance (checking wrong object, not actually completely removing the object, etc). Double-checking your code or stepping through it using a debugger (if game maker offers one of those) should help you find the issue.

Comment: I literally changed nothing from last time. It's just acting differently now.